# Python SQLite: Update Statement TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

For some reason I keep getting a

`findSenGroup = cur.executemany("UPDATE SEN_Table SET SenNumber = " + senNumStr + " WHERE FormName='" + nameGroup + "'")`

`TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) error`

with this update statement:

```
findSenGroup = cur.executemany("UPDATE SEN_Table SET SenNumber = " + senNumStr + " WHERE FormGroup='" + nameGroup + "'")
```

Table shown below

[image]

`senNumStr` is a the number that i want to update a column to.

`nameGroup` is the name of the row of where I want `senNumStr` added tp

`````

Comment: [Don't build SQL using strings and `+`.](https://xkcd.com/327/) Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value. See the [`executemany` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to use `executemany` here when you're only executing a single statement. You could use simply:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE SEN_Table SET SenNumber = " + senNumStr + " WHERE FormName='" + nameGroup + "'")
```

It would be better to use a parameterised query rather than a formatted string though, to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE SEN_Table SET SenNumber = ? WHERE FormName = ?", (senNumStr, nameGroup))
```

Comment: thanks it worked. can't believe i missed that.Thanks for the SQL injection vulnerabilities tip.